# Do we absolutely have to change the limits of integration for this problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image: http://s17.postimage.org/ougz1sm8u/Untitled.jpg]

Do we absolutely have to change the limits of integration for this problem?

from $\int_{0}^{4\pi}$ to $\int_{0}^{\pi}$?

Comment: You can use $\TeX$ on this site by enclosing formulas in dollar signs; single dollar signs for inline formulas and double dollar signs for displayed equations. You can see the source code for any math formatting you see on this site by right-clicking on it and selecting "Show Math As:TeX Commands". [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a basic tutorial and quick reference. There's an "edit" link under the question.

Comment: $\pi$ is a Greek letter, spelled "pi" and you can use it in your post by writing \pi enlclosed in single dollar signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%28sin+t%29sqrt%28%28cos+t%29%2a%2a2%2B1%29+from+t%3D0+to+t%3D2pi) $t\mapsto |\sin t|\sqrt{\cos^2t+1}$ you will find that the part of it between $0$ and $2\pi$ consist of four identical pieces, though two of them are reversed. The reversals do not change the area *under* each pieces, so you can find the entire integral by integrating just one of them and then multiplying the result by $4$.

(This is progress partly because it allows you to get rid of the absolute value by restricting your attention to a range where $\sin t$ is non-negative).